# Perl Archive::Zip unexpected behavior

Tags: perl

I am wondering if this is a bug?

```
sub addFile {
    my $self = shift;

    my ($fileName, $newName, $compressionLevel);
    if (ref($_[0]) eq 'HASH') {
        $fileName         = $_[0]->{filename};
        $newName          = $_[0]->{zipName};
        $compressionLevel = $_[0]->{compressionLevel};
    } else {
        ($fileName, $newName, $compressionLevel) = @_;
    }

    if ($^O eq 'MSWin32' && $Archive::Zip::UNICODE) {
        $fileName = Win32::GetANSIPathName($fileName);
    }

    my $newMember = Archive::Zip::Member->newFromFile($fileName, $newName);
    $newMember->desiredCompressionLevel($compressionLevel);**
    if ($self->{'storeSymbolicLink'} && -l $fileName) {
        my $newMember =
          Archive::Zip::Member->newFromString(readlink $fileName, $newName);

        # For symbolic links, External File Attribute is set to 0xA1FF0000 by Info-ZIP
        $newMember->{'externalFileAttributes'} = 0xA1FF0000;
        $self->addMember($newMember);
    } else {
        $self->addMember($newMember);
    }

    return $newMember;
}
```

It is not checking if `$newMember` is defined before calling `desiredCompressionLevel()`

And in case I try to add a file that does not exist, I get this

```
Can't call method "desiredCompressionLevel" on an undefined value at C:/Perl5281/site/lib/Archive/Zip/Archive.pm line 256.
```

Shouldn't this `addFile()` check for this condition and return undef if unsuccessful in adding the file. The help seems to indicate that behavior

```
addFile( $fileName [, $newName, $compressionLevel ] )
addFile( { filename => $fileName [, zipName => $newName, compressionLevel => $compressionLevel } ] )
Append a member whose data comes from an external file, returning the member or undef.
```

Also in this function in the same module, it is checking the same condition and returning undef if unsuccessful (as expected)

```
sub updateMember {
    my $self = shift;

    my ($oldMember, $fileName);
    if (ref($_[0]) eq 'HASH') {
        $oldMember = $_[0]->{memberOrZipName};
        $fileName  = $_[0]->{name};
    } else {
        ($oldMember, $fileName) = @_;
    }

    if (!defined($fileName)) {
        _error("updateMember(): missing fileName argument");
        return undef;
    }

    my @newStat = stat($fileName);
    if (!@newStat) {
        _ioError("Can't stat $fileName");
        return undef;
    }

    my $isDir = -d _;

    my $memberName;

    if (ref($oldMember)) {
        $memberName = $oldMember->fileName();
    } else {
        $oldMember = $self->memberNamed($memberName = $oldMember)
          || $self->memberNamed($memberName =
              _asZipDirName($oldMember, $isDir));
    }

    unless (defined($oldMember)
        && $oldMember->lastModTime() == $newStat[9]
        && $oldMember->isDirectory() == $isDir
        && ($isDir || ($oldMember->uncompressedSize() == $newStat[7]))) {

        # create the new member
        my $newMember =
            $isDir
          ? Archive::Zip::Member->newDirectoryNamed($fileName, $memberName)
          : Archive::Zip::Member->newFromFile($fileName, $memberName);

        unless (defined($newMember)) {
            _error("creation of member $fileName failed in updateMember()");
            return undef;
        }**

        # replace old member or append new one
        if (defined($oldMember)) {
            $self->replaceMember($oldMember, $newMember);
        } else {
            $self->addMember($newMember);
        }

        return $newMember;
    }

    return $oldMember;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right and such a bug [was filed 9 years ago](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=55748) and [again 6 years ago](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=91148). Unfortunately it looks like nobody cared as is the case with [lots of other bug reports](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Dist/Display.html?Name=Archive-Zip) for this module.

Comment: thanks. I think I will just modify the .pm on my machine for now.